# Is there any way to force Amazon Instant Video into High Quality?

Tags: amazon, flash, streaming

I'm watching a movie that is very dark, and it looks awful in low quality.

Is it possible to force Amazon Instant Video into high quality?

<sub>I am OK with long buffering times.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you watch from the [Amazon Unbox Player](http://www.amazon.com/gp/video/ontv/player), you can wait for the movie to completely (or partially) download in high-ish quality before watching it.

Answer (score 15):

Add `/?forceBR=5` to the end of the link in your browser.